# Different behaviour of compiler when called in script by LaunchControl

Tags: bash, fortran, automated-tests, sh, gfortran

I'm trying to automatically compile and test code by

1. checking it out from the repository,
2. compiling it,
3. running several test cases

using scripts that are called by [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl) every day at midnight. I'm compiling with gfortran (gcc version 4.9.2 20141029) on OS X 10.10.3 and use `bash`. The problem I'm running into is that I get messages like

```
gfortran: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.3.0
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.o
```

which I do **not** get when I run the same scripts interactively. I've tried sourcing my `.profile` and `.bashrc` files to make sure the environments and variables should be identical, but this has no effect. In particular, it does not seem to make any difference whether I have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set the same way when I run interactively or through LaunchControl.

I'm running the scripts as `User Agents` in LaunchControl.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Here's the stripped-down script that is called by LaunchControl:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME="/tmp/out.txt"
/Users/xxx/scripts/script1.sh > $FILENAME 2>&1
```

And here's `script1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp/build-test/src
make clean
make
```

**EDIT 2:** This is a stripped-down version of the makefile:

```
SHELL= /bin/bash
EXEC= main
FC= gfortran
FFLAGS= -O3
LINKER= gfortran

SRCF90= file1.f90 file2.f90

%.o: %.f90
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
OBJF90= $(SRCF90:.f90=.o)

$(EXEC): $(OBJF90)
        $(LINKER) $(OBJF90) -o $@
```

Comment: What shell is LaunchControl using? Is it the same as you are using interactively? That message about `kern.osversion` looks interesting because it has a single single quote in it. Can you show us the script(s) in question?

Comment: I could show you the script, but there's a lot of stuff in there that's germane to the code being tested, so not relevant to what's causing problems. I will try to extract the essentials. In the meantime, my scripts start with `#!/bin/bash`, so I assume everything in it will be executed in the bash shell.

Comment: The shebang only matters if the script is marked executable and run as `/path/to/script.sh` but assuming that's the case then yes, the shebang controls the shell that runs the script. (But, for example, a shebang of `#!/bin/bash` won't run the script with bash if the script is run as `sh script.sh`.)

Comment: What does the makefile that this runs look like?

Comment: Yes, the script is marked executable and run as you indicated. I edited the question to show a stripped-down version of the makefile.

Comment: I found the problem: For some reason I don't fully understand yet, when the script is called by LaunchControl, an older version of the gfortran compiler is used.

Comment: Compare `PATH` in the two environments. This might be an xcode-select (or whatever that thing is) issue.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.